# Proof of $f(x)-f(0)=\int_0^x f'(t)dt$.

Tags: real-analysis

In a proof of my lecture, to prove that for $f\in \mathcal C^1(\mathbb R)$, $$f(x)-f(0)=\int_0^x f'(t)dt,$$
it's made as follow :

Let $0=t_0<t_1^{(n)}<...<t_{m_n}^{(n)}=x$ a family of partition with $\max|t_{i+1}^{(n)}-t_i^{(n)}|\to 0$ when $n\to \infty $. Then $$f(x)-f(0)=\sum_{i=0}^{m_n-1}f(t_{i+1}^{(n)})-f(t_i^{(n)}).\tag{*}$$

Set $h_i^{(n)}=t_{i+1}^{(n)}-t_i^{(n)}$. We have that $$f(t_{i+1}^{(n)})=f(t_i^{(n)})+f'\left(t_{i}^{(n)}\right)h_i^{(n)}+R_i^n(h_i^{(n)}),$$
where $R_i^n(h_i^{(n)})=o(h_i^{(n)})$.

Therefore $(*)$ becomes $$f(x)-f(0)=\sum_{i=0}^{m_n-1}f'(t_{i}^{(n)})h_i^{(n)}+\sum_{i=0}^{m_n-1}R_i^n(h_i^{(n)}).$$

We have that $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{i=0}^{m_n-1}f'(t_i^{(n)})h_i^{(n)}=\int_0^x f'(t)dt.$$

Now, it's written : The fact that $$\sum_{i=0}^{m_n-1}R_i^n(h_i^{(n)})=0,$$
is clear and thus, the claim follow.

**Question :** I tried to prove this last result, but it fail. I wrote $$R_i^{n}(h_i^{(n)})=h_i^{(n)}\varepsilon _i^n(h_i^{(n)}),$$
for some function $\varepsilon _i^n$ s.t. $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to 0}\varepsilon_i^n(t)=0$. But now, I don't really see why $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{i=0}^{m_n-1}h_i^{(n)}\varepsilon _i^n(h_i^{(n)})=0.$$

---

I don't want to use Mean value theorem, because the aim is to make a proof that I can adapt to prove Itô formula.

Comment: What do you want to prove then? You can show, without using mean value theorem, that $|f(x + h) - f(x)| \leq M|h|$ for $M$ a bound of $f'$ between $x$ and $x + h.$ Would this do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can give a much nicer proof with no "error terms" using the Mean Value Theorem.

**Edit:** I've been told that the OP doesn't want to use MVT because the goal is Ito's  formula. I know nothing whatever about that,  so I have no idea whether it helps, but one can still base a proof of FTC on MVT in some contexts where MVT cannot be applied directly (giving a proof much simpler than the proof in the OP, which really seems like the hardest possible way to do it). See **Banach Spaces** at the bottom...

Suppose WLOG $f$ is real-valued. Say $0=x_0<\dots<x_n=1$.  For each   $j$ there exists $\xi_j\in(x_{j-1},x_j)$ with $$f(x_j)-f(x_{j-1})=f'(\xi_j)(x_j-x_{j-1}).$$So $$f(1)-f(0)=\sum_{j=1}^nf'(\xi_j)(x_j-x_{j-1}),$$which is precisely a Riemann sum for $\int_0^1f'(t)\,dt$...

**Edit:** I've been asked how this proves the exercise. It doesn't prove that thing about the limit of the sum of $R_i^n$, except indirectly, by showing that $f(1)-f(0)=\int_0^1 f'(t)\,dt$. It *does*  give a much simpler proof that $f(1)-f(0)=\int_0^1 f'$, and under weaker hypotheses:

> > > **FTC for the Riemann Integral.** Suppose $f:[0,1]\to\Bbb R$ is differentiable and $f'$ is Riemann integrable. Then $f(1)=f(0)=\int_0^1f'(t)\,dt$.

Proof. Let $\epsilon>0$. Choose $\delta>0$ so that if $0=x_0<\dots<x_n=1$, $x_j-x_{j-1}<\delta$ and $\xi_j\in(x_{j-1},x_j)$ for every $j$ then $$\left|\sum_{j=1}^n f'(\xi_j)(x_j-x_{j-1})-\int_0^1f'(t)\,dt\right|<\epsilon.$$Using MVT as above shows that $$\left|f(1)-f(0)-\int_0^1f'(t)\,dt\right|<\epsilon.$$

**Banach Spaces**

Consider this version of FTC:

> > **BSFTC** If $X$ is a Banach space and $f:[0,1]\to X$ is continuously differentiable then $f(1)-f(0)=\int_0^1f'(t)\,dt$.

Proof 1. By Hahn-Banach it's enough to show that $$\Lambda(f(1)-f(0))=\Lambda\int_0^1 f'(t)\,dt$$for every $\Lambda\in X^*$. But $(\Lambda\circ f)'=\Lambda\circ(f')$, so this follows from the scalar-valued FTC: $$\Lambda\int_0^1 f'(t)=\int_0^1\Lambda f'(t)=\Lambda f(1)-\Lambda f(0).$$

Proof 2. Start with the other version of FTC:

> > **BSFTC.0** If $X$ is a Banach space, $f:\Bbb R\to X$ is continuous and $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)$ then $F'=f$.

Proof: If $h>0$ then $$\begin{align}\left\|\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}h-f(x)\right\|&=\left\|\frac1h\int_x^{x+h}(f(t)-f(x))\,dt\right\|
\\&\le\frac1h\int_x^{x+h}||f(x)-f(t)||\,dt;\end{align}$$the last integral is less than $\epsilon$ if $h$ is small enough, since $f$ is continuous.

BSFTC.0 implies BSFTC  Suppose $f:[0,1]\to X$ is continuously differentiable. Let $$g(x)=\int_0^x f'(t)\,dt.$$Then BSFTC.0 shows that $(f-g)'=0$. Hence, again using Hahn-Banach to reduce to the scalar case, $f-g$ is constant, in particular $$f(1)-g(1)=f(0)-g(0)=f(0).$$

Again, I know nothing about that Ito thing, but both of those proofs are so straightforward surely one of them works?

Comment: Sorry, how does this prove the exercise?

Comment: I guess all reduces to show that "Darboux" integral and "Riemann" integral are the same concept. And this, I believe, is proven as was done in the other answer.

Comment: @WillM. I'm not sure what "the exercise" is. It doesn't prove the limit you proved in your answer --  it does prove FTC for the Riemann integral.

Comment: +1 this is the proof which everyone must learn and appreciate. It is simple and shows that mean value theorem is a powerful tool.

Comment: @WillM.: The point of the exercise is a proof of FTC. But the approach used in the question is unnecessarily complicated. Also the equivalence of Darboux and Riemann integral is not  needed. The key here is the definition of Riemann integral as a limit of Riemann sums and the use of mean value theorem.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Indeed. I noticed this argument some time ago  when I was teaching "advanced calculus". Seems to me it's a good reason for the definition of the Riemann integral being what it is - it's just exactly what's needed to make the argument work.

Comment: I don't want to use Mean value theorem, because the aim is to prove Itô formula.

Comment: @user649261 See edit...

Comment: The problem with Itô integral it's you can't take any $t_i^*\in [t_{i},t_{i+1}]$ in $\lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{k=1}^n f(B_{t_i^*})(B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_i})$ because the Brownian motion is not with bounded variation. You must take $t_i^*=t_i$, that's why the MVT can't be used. Unfortunately, none of the situation match to my problem. Anyways, thank you very much for this answer, I'm sure it's very helpful for others :)

Answer (score 2):

That claim is not at all obvious. Consider the function $\varphi(x, h) = \dfrac{f(x + h) - f(x) - f'(x) h}{h}$ for $h \neq 0$ and $\varphi(x, 0) = 0,$ which is continuous in the two variables $x$ and $h.$ The only pesky detail is continuity at the points where $h = 0$ but note that since $f$ is of class $\mathscr{C}^1$ then we can do
\begin{align*}
\varphi(x, h) = f'(c(x, h)) - f'(x)
\end{align*}
with $c(x, h)$ lying between $x$ and $x + h.$ If now $h \to 0,$ $c(x, h) \to x$ and then, continuity follows. Notice that $\varphi$ is then is uniformly continuous for $(x, h) \in [0, T] \times [0, 1],$ say (apply Heine-Cantor's theorem). Then, the function $R_i^n(h) = \varphi \left(t_i^{(n)}, h^{(n)} \right)$ can be made uniformly small if the $\left( t_i^{(n)}, h^{(n)} \right)$ are closed enough (consecutive indices). The exercise now follows with your last remarks. (Side note, I have found many times "obvious claims" and this had made me not very fond of mathematicians in general.)

Comment: So the key is really to take the $\varepsilon _i^n$ as your function $\varphi $ (and not take any function $\varepsilon _i^n$) right ?

Comment: The point is that $\varepsilon_i^n$ can be made _uniformly small._ Observe that your $\varepsilon_i^n( \cdot ) = \varphi \left( t_i^{(n)}, \cdot \right).$

Answer (score 0):

Well the approach used in your proof is clumsy to say the least. Let's simplify the notation a bit and have a partition $$P=\{x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n\}$$ of $[0,x]$ such that as $n\to\infty $ the norm $||P||=\max_{1\leq i\leq n} (x_i-x_{i-1})$ tends to $0$.

Your proof writes $f(x) - f(0)$ as a telescopic sum $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\{f'(x_{i-1})(x_i-x_{i-1})+o(x_i-x_{i-1})\}$$ Instead of analyzing the error terms $o(x_i-x_{i-1})$ it is better to note that $$f(x_i) - f(x_{i-1})=f'(\xi_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})$$ for some $\xi_i\in(x_{i-1},x_i)$ and then the error terms can be expressed as $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}o(x_i-x_{i-1})=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\{f'(\xi_i)-f'(x_{i-1})\}(x_i-x_{i-1})$$ By definition of Riemann integral the sum on RHS tends to $0$ if $f'$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,x]$ as the norm of partitions under consideration tends to $0$.

This is easy to observe if the function being integrated (here $f'$) is continuous because then it is also uniformly continuous on the corresponding closed interval. Thus for any $\epsilon>0$ we have a $\delta>0$ such that $$|f'(p) - f'(q) |<\frac {\epsilon} {x} $$ whenever $p\in[0,x],q\in[0,x],|p-q|<\delta $. If the norm $||P||<\delta$ then we have $$\left|\sum_{i=1}^{n}\{f'(\xi_i)-f'(x_{i-1})\}(x_i-x_{i-1})\right|\leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}|f'(\xi_i)-f'(x_{i-1})|(x_i-x_{i-1})$$ and the RHS is clearly less than $$\frac{\epsilon } {x}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-x_{i-1})=\epsilon$$

Comment: I don't want to use mean value theorem, because the aim is to make a proof that I can use to prove Itô formula.

Comment: @user649261: then you are out of luck. The fundamental theorem of calculus does require mean value theorem. Also how is the use of mean value theorem a roadblock for proving Ito formula (I am not aware of what Ito formula is)?

Comment: The problem with the stochastic integral (wrt brownian motion), it's that the brownian motion has not bounded variation, and thus the sum $\lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{i=1}^{m_n-1}f(B_{t_i*})(B_{t_{i+1}}-B_{t_i})$ depend on $t_i^*\in [t_i,t_{i+1}]$. And what gives the Ito integral is $t_{i}^*=t_i$ only. So you can't use Mean value theorem.

Comment: @user649261 Unfortunately I have no idea of stochastic process and I don't know how it is related to the usual calculus.

Comment: @user649261 I have seen the proof of Itō's theorem and what they usually do is to write $f(B_{t^*_i}) = f(t_i) + \delta_i$ and then, show that in $\mathscr{L}^1,$ $\sum_i \delta_i (B_{t_{i + 1}} - B_{t_i})$ converges to zero. Then, take a subsequence that converges uniformly. Cheers